# Optimizing a Complex T-SQL Statement Designed to SUM Financial Data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to optimize a process for creating a SQL report based upon our company's financial data.  The end result I am looking to achieve is a new table that contains the compiled data for the past three years (current year plus last year and the year before).  I will take this data and display it in a graph with each year getting its own line (thus showing the trends, etc.)

The problems are as follows:

1. The data is in two different tables
   (one for current year and one for
   previous years).
2. The data needs to be a cumulative SUM per week.  Thus week two is a
   sum from day one through the end of
   week two while week three will be a
   sum from day one through the end of
   week three.
3. The fiscal year starts June 1, which splits a calendar week number
   (thus if you operate by converting
   dates to week numbers and do a GROUP
   BY on the week numbers, you are
   going to throw off the data because
   data from the end of the year (week
   23) gets put with data from the
   beginning of the year (week 23).
4. The archive data is stored by year number, but that year number is
   the same for the entire year, which
   means the data stored under 2008
   goes from 6/1/2008 to 5/31/2009. 
   Thus, you can’t use the year number
   in the lookup as the year number of
   the values you are trying to extract
   (in case you decide to build dates
   in order to uniformly look for
   data).

While I am designing this so that it is run on a schedule (as a standard ETL process), I still want it to be efficient and manageable.  Right now, I have a working solution.  However, I am not comfortable with it.  It is a cludge.  I just got something to work (since I had to show the graph it is supporting to the president of our organization today).  Now I need to do it right.  What I have now is six update statements that write to my new table.  Each statement pulls data for half a year.  Two statements per year (thus six total).  I do this because in my final table I have a list of months and days that I want to do the lookup based upon (6/7, 6/14, 6/21, etc.)  This way each dataset is uniform and I don’t have the issue of week number rollover.  I build the date off of this month and day number and add in the year number.  Since the year number changes half way through (see problem #4), I go up to the end of the year with one SQL statement then pick up at the beginning of the calendar year with the next since one statement increments the year number for the date lookup and one does not.

Here is an example of my code (for those of you who might know, this is operating against a Microsoft Dynamics Great Plains database):

```
/* Second half of last year */
UPDATE ProfitLoss
SET ProfitLoss.monCashOneYearBack = upd.Balance
FROM ProfitLoss
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT (
            SELECT (SUM(cumulative.CRDTAMNT) - SUM(cumulative.DEBITAMT)) AS Result
            FROM GL30000 AS cumulative
            INNER JOIN GL00100 ON cumulative.ActIndx = GL00100.ActIndx
            WHERE GL00100.ActNumbr_1=10 
                AND GL00100.ActNumbr_2=1020 
                AND GL00100.ActNumbr_3=000 
                AND GL00100.ActNumbr_4=00
                AND cumulative.HSTYEAR=2009 
                AND cumulative.TRXDATE <= CAST(CAST(2010 AS varchar) + '-' + 
                    CAST(ProfitLoss.intMonthNumber AS varchar) + '-' + 
                    CAST(ProfitLoss.intDayNumber AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
        ) AS Balance, intOrder, intWeekNumber
FROM ProfitLoss
WHERE intOrder > 30
) AS upd ON ProfitLoss.intWeekNumber = upd.intWeekNumber
```

In case you are wondering, this is just scratch code.  The year number is still hard-coded.  If I were to make this production code it would be a variable.  The basic overview of this code is that I am doing a SELECT on my new table (ProfitLoss), doing a SUM of my credits minus a SUM of my debits from my history table based upon the date built using my new table’s month and date, then I am using that Balance data as the value to insert into the ProfitLoss table in the appropriate column (since I only operate on one column at a time, and only half of that).

All of this works, but it is terribly inefficient.  What I want to know is if I am missing something obvious.  Is there a better way to do this?  I would love to create one statement that handled it all.  I do have access to (and skill with) SSIS in case I need to bring in the big guns for a better method of ETL but I really think there is a better way of doing this using T-SQL.  Any thought on what that way might be would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:  The table schema that I am pulling from has only a few columns that matter.  They are:

```
CRDTAMT, DEBITAMT, TRXDATE, and HSTYEAR (OPENYEAR for the current table)
```

The rest are just columns that I use for data filtering/etc. which is outside the scope of this question.  Basically, the above fields hold the data I want.  For example, when something is purchased on June 9th, we will get an entry here that has a zero in the CRDTAMT field, $100 in the DEBITAMT field, a TRXDATE of 6/9/2009, and a HSTYEAR of 2009.  We will have multiple transactions like this.  I want to collapse them down into one cumulative number each week.  Thus, if this were the only transaction since June 1, we would have a zero for the week ending 6/7 and we would have a negative $100 for the week ending 6/14 and that negative $100 would carry over in 6/21 and on.  This data would be one of the three years worth I would be capturing.

Comment: Have you considered adding a date table that can translate your transaction dates into reporting columns? For example, you would have every date from 6/1/2000 through 5/31/2019. Then you have columns for REPORTING_YEAR, REPORTING_MONTH, REPORTING_WEEK, REPORTING_QUARTER, WEEK_STARTING, WEEK_ENDING, etc which maps to your fiscal year.  That would make grouping rows by reporting periods much easier.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you want the data grouped weekly? With Sunday being the week start day?  Inevitably the last or first week of the will contain data that spans the Fiscal year of 6/1.  Is the problem trying to combine the data from the two different tables (current and historical) to get data for the whole week?

Comment: Also, is the schema the same between the current and historical tables?  In a pinch, could you UNION ALL them together to get data that spanned different fiscal years?

Comment: @beach  I see what you are saying about the reporting table, but it is a little too static for me.  My output table has the reporting month and reporting day that I can use to build the data for each year.  This way I can always run my reports off of the same three columns (current year, one year back, and two  years back) instead of needing to know which columns to look for.  I also store what year they represent so that I can display that as well on the report.

Comment: @beach I do want the data to be grouped weekly but I resigned myself to grouping the weeks with the "week" ending June 7th of each year so that even though that might be the middle of a true week, I am not cutting off data on either side.  It would be a problem to combine data across a year since this would be data for two different fiscal years.  As for the schema, it is basically the same between the two tables.  The only difference is the reporting year column, which is CRNTYEAR for the current year and HSTYEAR for the archive data.  UNION ALL wouldn't really help me reduce complexity here.

Comment: The dates table is supposed to be static :).  Are you sure crossing financial boundaries is a problem? But perhaps it doesn't matter since you are always defining Week 1 as 6/1 through 6/7. I didn't understand that before.  But how will you account for the days before 6/1? Where will the extra days go? Week 53?  For example, where does 5/31/2010 go? Week 52 would be 5/24/2010-5/30/2010.

Comment: @beach I am calling 6/7 week 1 so I end up at week 52 by the end.  However, I don't display a week number, since that would be confusing.  Instead, I display 6/7, 6/14, etc. without the year on the end.  This allows the three years of data to align on my graph nicely.  As for crossing the financial boundaries, yes that is a big deal.  The last day of the year contains some special charges and credits that would throw off a week entirely if it was put in the wrong year.

Comment: The problem is that there is not exactly 52 weeks in 365 (or 366) days.  The last full 7-day week ends on 5/30/2010. What happens to 5/31/2010?

Comment: I cheat :-)  The last week is 8 days long.  Also, if we have a leap year I have another week with 8 days.  The main issue, however, is how do I make this query set simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a couple of auxiliary tables, then the problem becomes straight forward.  I've prototyped the solution and from what information you've provided so far, I don't see why this doesn't meet your needs.

[SQL containing DML and queries](http://www.dropfiles.net/download.php?file=560stackoverflow_5892303.sql)

[Excel file used to create your weekly financial reporting structure](http://www.dropfiles.net/download.php?file=49stackoverflow_5892303.xlsx)

Cut to the chase - you wanted a simple query to replace your existing methodology. Here it is (with new schema that is defined in the attached SQL):

```
SELECT 
    W.YEAR, 
    W.WEEK_NUMBER, 
    SUM(NETAMT) AS NETAMT, 
    MIN(RT.YTDAMT) AS YTDAMT /* we only want one row from the cross apply return */
FROM #ProfitLossDaily PLD
INNER JOIN #Weeks W ON PLD.TRXDATE BETWEEN W.WEEK_STARTING AND W.WEEK_ENDING
CROSS APPLY (   
    SELECT SUM(NETAMT) AS YTDAMT
    FROM #ProfitLossDaily PLD2
    INNER JOIN #Weeks W2 ON PLD2.TRXDATE BETWEEN W2.WEEK_STARTING AND W2.WEEK_ENDING
    WHERE W2.YEAR = W.YEAR
        AND W2.WEEK_NUMBER <= W.WEEK_NUMBER
) as RT
GROUP BY W.YEAR, W.WEEK_NUMBER
ORDER BY W.YEAR, W.WEEK_NUMBER
```

The attached SQL file contains sample data and queries that populate the new table schema and return the results.

If you populate the ProfitLossDaily table via nightly job, then you can run the MERGE INTO right afterward (see the attached SQL file) to always have updated data ready.

**SCHEMA** *(in case the attached SQL goes away sometime)*

```
CREATE TABLE #Weeks (
    YEAR INTEGER, 
    WEEK_NUMBER INTEGER,
    WEEK_STARTING DATE,
    WEEK_ENDING DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (YEAR,WEEK_NUMBER)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #ProfitLossDaily (
    TRXDATE DATE PRIMARY KEY, 
    CRDTAMT DECIMAL(38,8) NOT NULL,
    DEBITAMT DECIMAL(38,8) NOT NULL,
    NETAMT AS CRDTAMT - DEBITAMT
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #ProfitLoss (
    YEAR INTEGER, 
    WEEK_NUMBER INTEGER,
    NETAMT DECIMAL(38,8) NOT NULL,
    YTDAMT DECIMAL(38,8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (YEAR,WEEK_NUMBER)
)
GO
```

**Nightly Job to populate ProfitLoss**

```
MERGE INTO #ProfitLoss AS Target
USING (
    SELECT 
        W.YEAR, 
        W.WEEK_NUMBER, 
        SUM(NETAMT) AS NETAMT, 
        MIN(RT.YTDAMT) AS YTDAMT /* we only want one row from the cross apply return */
    FROM #ProfitLossDaily PLD
    INNER JOIN #Weeks W ON PLD.TRXDATE BETWEEN W.WEEK_STARTING AND W.WEEK_ENDING
    CROSS APPLY (   
        SELECT SUM(NETAMT) AS YTDAMT
        FROM #ProfitLossDaily PLD2
        INNER JOIN #Weeks W2 ON PLD2.TRXDATE BETWEEN W2.WEEK_STARTING AND W2.WEEK_ENDING
        WHERE W2.YEAR = W.YEAR
            AND W2.WEEK_NUMBER <= W.WEEK_NUMBER
    ) as RT
    WHERE W.WEEK_STARTING >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BY W.YEAR, W.WEEK_NUMBER
) AS Source ON Target.YEAR = Source.YEAR AND Target.WEEK_NUMBER = Source.WEEK_NUMBER
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET NETAMT = Source.NETAMT, YTDAMT = Source.YTDAMT
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (YEAR, WEEK_NUMBER, NETAMT, YTDAMT) VALUES (YEAR, WEEK_NUMBER, NETAMT, YTDAMT);
```

**Populate WEEKS** *(with your financial reporting structure)*

```
/* Populate WEEKS table with the financial reporting period definitions */
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,1,'2008-06-01','2008-06-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,2,'2008-06-08','2008-06-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,3,'2008-06-15','2008-06-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,4,'2008-06-22','2008-06-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,5,'2008-06-29','2008-07-05')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,6,'2008-07-06','2008-07-12')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,7,'2008-07-13','2008-07-19')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,8,'2008-07-20','2008-07-26')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,9,'2008-07-27','2008-08-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,10,'2008-08-03','2008-08-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,11,'2008-08-10','2008-08-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,12,'2008-08-17','2008-08-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,13,'2008-08-24','2008-08-30')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,14,'2008-08-31','2008-09-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,15,'2008-09-07','2008-09-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,16,'2008-09-14','2008-09-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,17,'2008-09-21','2008-09-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,18,'2008-09-28','2008-10-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,19,'2008-10-05','2008-10-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,20,'2008-10-12','2008-10-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,21,'2008-10-19','2008-10-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,22,'2008-10-26','2008-11-01')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,23,'2008-11-02','2008-11-08')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,24,'2008-11-09','2008-11-15')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,25,'2008-11-16','2008-11-22')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,26,'2008-11-23','2008-11-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,27,'2008-11-30','2008-12-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,28,'2008-12-07','2008-12-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,29,'2008-12-14','2008-12-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,30,'2008-12-21','2008-12-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,31,'2008-12-28','2009-01-03')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,32,'2009-01-04','2009-01-10')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,33,'2009-01-11','2009-01-17')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,34,'2009-01-18','2009-01-24')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,35,'2009-01-25','2009-01-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,36,'2009-02-01','2009-02-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,37,'2009-02-08','2009-02-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,38,'2009-02-15','2009-02-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,39,'2009-02-22','2009-02-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,40,'2009-03-01','2009-03-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,41,'2009-03-08','2009-03-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,42,'2009-03-15','2009-03-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,43,'2009-03-22','2009-03-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,44,'2009-03-29','2009-04-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,45,'2009-04-05','2009-04-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,46,'2009-04-12','2009-04-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,47,'2009-04-19','2009-04-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,48,'2009-04-26','2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,49,'2009-05-03','2009-05-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,50,'2009-05-10','2009-05-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,51,'2009-05-17','2009-05-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2008,52,'2009-05-24','2009-05-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,1,'2009-06-01','2009-06-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,2,'2009-06-08','2009-06-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,3,'2009-06-15','2009-06-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,4,'2009-06-22','2009-06-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,5,'2009-06-29','2009-07-05')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,6,'2009-07-06','2009-07-12')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,7,'2009-07-13','2009-07-19')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,8,'2009-07-20','2009-07-26')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,9,'2009-07-27','2009-08-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,10,'2009-08-03','2009-08-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,11,'2009-08-10','2009-08-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,12,'2009-08-17','2009-08-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,13,'2009-08-24','2009-08-30')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,14,'2009-08-31','2009-09-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,15,'2009-09-07','2009-09-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,16,'2009-09-14','2009-09-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,17,'2009-09-21','2009-09-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,18,'2009-09-28','2009-10-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,19,'2009-10-05','2009-10-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,20,'2009-10-12','2009-10-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,21,'2009-10-19','2009-10-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,22,'2009-10-26','2009-11-01')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,23,'2009-11-02','2009-11-08')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,24,'2009-11-09','2009-11-15')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,25,'2009-11-16','2009-11-22')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,26,'2009-11-23','2009-11-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,27,'2009-11-30','2009-12-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,28,'2009-12-07','2009-12-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,29,'2009-12-14','2009-12-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,30,'2009-12-21','2009-12-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,31,'2009-12-28','2010-01-03')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,32,'2010-01-04','2010-01-10')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,33,'2010-01-11','2010-01-17')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,34,'2010-01-18','2010-01-24')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,35,'2010-01-25','2010-01-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,36,'2010-02-01','2010-02-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,37,'2010-02-08','2010-02-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,38,'2010-02-15','2010-02-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,39,'2010-02-22','2010-02-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,40,'2010-03-01','2010-03-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,41,'2010-03-08','2010-03-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,42,'2010-03-15','2010-03-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,43,'2010-03-22','2010-03-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,44,'2010-03-29','2010-04-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,45,'2010-04-05','2010-04-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,46,'2010-04-12','2010-04-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,47,'2010-04-19','2010-04-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,48,'2010-04-26','2010-05-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,49,'2010-05-03','2010-05-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,50,'2010-05-10','2010-05-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,51,'2010-05-17','2010-05-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2009,52,'2010-05-24','2010-05-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,1,'2010-06-01','2010-06-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,2,'2010-06-08','2010-06-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,3,'2010-06-15','2010-06-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,4,'2010-06-22','2010-06-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,5,'2010-06-29','2010-07-05')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,6,'2010-07-06','2010-07-12')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,7,'2010-07-13','2010-07-19')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,8,'2010-07-20','2010-07-26')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,9,'2010-07-27','2010-08-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,10,'2010-08-03','2010-08-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,11,'2010-08-10','2010-08-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,12,'2010-08-17','2010-08-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,13,'2010-08-24','2010-08-30')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,14,'2010-08-31','2010-09-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,15,'2010-09-07','2010-09-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,16,'2010-09-14','2010-09-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,17,'2010-09-21','2010-09-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,18,'2010-09-28','2010-10-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,19,'2010-10-05','2010-10-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,20,'2010-10-12','2010-10-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,21,'2010-10-19','2010-10-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,22,'2010-10-26','2010-11-01')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,23,'2010-11-02','2010-11-08')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,24,'2010-11-09','2010-11-15')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,25,'2010-11-16','2010-11-22')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,26,'2010-11-23','2010-11-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,27,'2010-11-30','2010-12-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,28,'2010-12-07','2010-12-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,29,'2010-12-14','2010-12-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,30,'2010-12-21','2010-12-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,31,'2010-12-28','2011-01-03')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,32,'2011-01-04','2011-01-10')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,33,'2011-01-11','2011-01-17')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,34,'2011-01-18','2011-01-24')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,35,'2011-01-25','2011-01-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,36,'2011-02-01','2011-02-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,37,'2011-02-08','2011-02-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,38,'2011-02-15','2011-02-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,39,'2011-02-22','2011-02-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,40,'2011-03-01','2011-03-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,41,'2011-03-08','2011-03-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,42,'2011-03-15','2011-03-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,43,'2011-03-22','2011-03-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,44,'2011-03-29','2011-04-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,45,'2011-04-05','2011-04-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,46,'2011-04-12','2011-04-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,47,'2011-04-19','2011-04-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,48,'2011-04-26','2011-05-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,49,'2011-05-03','2011-05-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,50,'2011-05-10','2011-05-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,51,'2011-05-17','2011-05-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2010,52,'2011-05-24','2011-05-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,1,'2011-06-01','2011-06-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,2,'2011-06-08','2011-06-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,3,'2011-06-15','2011-06-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,4,'2011-06-22','2011-06-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,5,'2011-06-29','2011-07-05')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,6,'2011-07-06','2011-07-12')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,7,'2011-07-13','2011-07-19')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,8,'2011-07-20','2011-07-26')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,9,'2011-07-27','2011-08-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,10,'2011-08-03','2011-08-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,11,'2011-08-10','2011-08-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,12,'2011-08-17','2011-08-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,13,'2011-08-24','2011-08-30')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,14,'2011-08-31','2011-09-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,15,'2011-09-07','2011-09-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,16,'2011-09-14','2011-09-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,17,'2011-09-21','2011-09-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,18,'2011-09-28','2011-10-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,19,'2011-10-05','2011-10-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,20,'2011-10-12','2011-10-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,21,'2011-10-19','2011-10-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,22,'2011-10-26','2011-11-01')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,23,'2011-11-02','2011-11-08')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,24,'2011-11-09','2011-11-15')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,25,'2011-11-16','2011-11-22')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,26,'2011-11-23','2011-11-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,27,'2011-11-30','2011-12-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,28,'2011-12-07','2011-12-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,29,'2011-12-14','2011-12-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,30,'2011-12-21','2011-12-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,31,'2011-12-28','2012-01-03')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,32,'2012-01-04','2012-01-10')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,33,'2012-01-11','2012-01-17')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,34,'2012-01-18','2012-01-24')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,35,'2012-01-25','2012-01-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,36,'2012-02-01','2012-02-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,37,'2012-02-08','2012-02-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,38,'2012-02-15','2012-02-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,39,'2012-02-22','2012-02-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,40,'2012-03-01','2012-03-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,41,'2012-03-08','2012-03-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,42,'2012-03-15','2012-03-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,43,'2012-03-22','2012-03-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,44,'2012-03-29','2012-04-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,45,'2012-04-05','2012-04-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,46,'2012-04-12','2012-04-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,47,'2012-04-19','2012-04-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,48,'2012-04-26','2012-05-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,49,'2012-05-03','2012-05-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,50,'2012-05-10','2012-05-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,51,'2012-05-17','2012-05-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2011,52,'2012-05-24','2012-05-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,1,'2012-06-01','2012-06-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,2,'2012-06-08','2012-06-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,3,'2012-06-15','2012-06-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,4,'2012-06-22','2012-06-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,5,'2012-06-29','2012-07-05')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,6,'2012-07-06','2012-07-12')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,7,'2012-07-13','2012-07-19')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,8,'2012-07-20','2012-07-26')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,9,'2012-07-27','2012-08-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,10,'2012-08-03','2012-08-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,11,'2012-08-10','2012-08-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,12,'2012-08-17','2012-08-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,13,'2012-08-24','2012-08-30')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,14,'2012-08-31','2012-09-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,15,'2012-09-07','2012-09-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,16,'2012-09-14','2012-09-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,17,'2012-09-21','2012-09-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,18,'2012-09-28','2012-10-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,19,'2012-10-05','2012-10-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,20,'2012-10-12','2012-10-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,21,'2012-10-19','2012-10-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,22,'2012-10-26','2012-11-01')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,23,'2012-11-02','2012-11-08')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,24,'2012-11-09','2012-11-15')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,25,'2012-11-16','2012-11-22')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,26,'2012-11-23','2012-11-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,27,'2012-11-30','2012-12-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,28,'2012-12-07','2012-12-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,29,'2012-12-14','2012-12-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,30,'2012-12-21','2012-12-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,31,'2012-12-28','2013-01-03')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,32,'2013-01-04','2013-01-10')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,33,'2013-01-11','2013-01-17')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,34,'2013-01-18','2013-01-24')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,35,'2013-01-25','2013-01-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,36,'2013-02-01','2013-02-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,37,'2013-02-08','2013-02-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,38,'2013-02-15','2013-02-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,39,'2013-02-22','2013-02-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,40,'2013-03-01','2013-03-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,41,'2013-03-08','2013-03-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,42,'2013-03-15','2013-03-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,43,'2013-03-22','2013-03-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,44,'2013-03-29','2013-04-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,45,'2013-04-05','2013-04-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,46,'2013-04-12','2013-04-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,47,'2013-04-19','2013-04-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,48,'2013-04-26','2013-05-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,49,'2013-05-03','2013-05-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,50,'2013-05-10','2013-05-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,51,'2013-05-17','2013-05-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2012,52,'2013-05-24','2013-05-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,1,'2013-06-01','2013-06-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,2,'2013-06-08','2013-06-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,3,'2013-06-15','2013-06-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,4,'2013-06-22','2013-06-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,5,'2013-06-29','2013-07-05')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,6,'2013-07-06','2013-07-12')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,7,'2013-07-13','2013-07-19')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,8,'2013-07-20','2013-07-26')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,9,'2013-07-27','2013-08-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,10,'2013-08-03','2013-08-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,11,'2013-08-10','2013-08-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,12,'2013-08-17','2013-08-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,13,'2013-08-24','2013-08-30')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,14,'2013-08-31','2013-09-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,15,'2013-09-07','2013-09-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,16,'2013-09-14','2013-09-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,17,'2013-09-21','2013-09-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,18,'2013-09-28','2013-10-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,19,'2013-10-05','2013-10-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,20,'2013-10-12','2013-10-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,21,'2013-10-19','2013-10-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,22,'2013-10-26','2013-11-01')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,23,'2013-11-02','2013-11-08')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,24,'2013-11-09','2013-11-15')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,25,'2013-11-16','2013-11-22')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,26,'2013-11-23','2013-11-29')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,27,'2013-11-30','2013-12-06')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,28,'2013-12-07','2013-12-13')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,29,'2013-12-14','2013-12-20')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,30,'2013-12-21','2013-12-27')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,31,'2013-12-28','2014-01-03')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,32,'2014-01-04','2014-01-10')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,33,'2014-01-11','2014-01-17')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,34,'2014-01-18','2014-01-24')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,35,'2014-01-25','2014-01-31')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,36,'2014-02-01','2014-02-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,37,'2014-02-08','2014-02-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,38,'2014-02-15','2014-02-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,39,'2014-02-22','2014-02-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,40,'2014-03-01','2014-03-07')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,41,'2014-03-08','2014-03-14')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,42,'2014-03-15','2014-03-21')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,43,'2014-03-22','2014-03-28')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,44,'2014-03-29','2014-04-04')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,45,'2014-04-05','2014-04-11')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,46,'2014-04-12','2014-04-18')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,47,'2014-04-19','2014-04-25')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,48,'2014-04-26','2014-05-02')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,49,'2014-05-03','2014-05-09')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,50,'2014-05-10','2014-05-16')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,51,'2014-05-17','2014-05-23')
INSERT INTO #WEEKS VALUES (2013,52,'2014-05-24','2014-05-31')
GO
```

**Populate #ProfitLossDaily with sample data**

```
/* In production, this would come from GL30000 or the history table  */
WITH integers(i) AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS i 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1 FROM integers WHERE i < 10
)
INSERT INTO #ProfitLossDaily (TRXDATE, CRDTAMT, DEBITAMT)
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(day,i, WEEK_STARTING) AS TRXDATE, 
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1100 AS CRDTAMT, /* random number */
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1000 AS DEBITAMT /* random number */
    FROM #WEEKS, integers 
    WHERE DATEADD(day,i, WEEK_STARTING) BETWEEN WEEK_STARTING AND WEEK_ENDING
        AND YEAR BETWEEN 2005 AND 2011
        AND DATEADD(day,i, WEEK_STARTING) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GO
```

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of work.  Thanks for the great effort.  I will review this and see how it works for me.  Because I am out of the office until Monday I'm not sure if I will be able to test it before then (busy weekend planned).  Rest assured, however, that I will test it out and get back to you.

Comment: @Biggs - So how did the testing go?

Comment: still working on it (sorry, got delayed by a viewing - the funeral is tomorrow).  I should have something soon.

Comment: @biggs - oh no, sorry to hear about that.  No rush on this.  I'll be here whenever you are ready.

Comment: I was finally able to finish implementing your code into my environment.  I had to modify it a bit since I'm pulling from two different tables in a UNION query instead of using the #ProfitLossDaily table (one less step).  Thanks for the hard work.  Also, as a side note, the attachments are not available (not that I needed them).